# Constructing a cell that input value, display value, but the cell value is something else?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

So, the title is kinda confusing.
I'll use an example.
I'd like to input a value, 3, on cell A1. 
And I'd like the cell to do some math, for example, times 3 plus 1.
Next, return the value to cell A1, BUT
when I clicked on the cell A1, I wish it to display the math formula.
So here's what I got:

```
Sub A()
    Dim term1 As Double
    Dim term2 As Double

    Range("A1").NumberFormat = "General"
    term1 = Range("A1").Value
    term2 = term1 * 3 + 1
    Range("A1").Value = term2
    term3 = term2
    term3 = """term1 * 3 + 1"""
    Range("A1").NumberFormatLocal = term3   
End Sub
```

I've got it to do what I want it to do, which is take a value and then return it. However, I seem to not able to make `.NumberFormatLocal`take `term2` value as string.
Such that when the operation is done, I see 4 displayed on the cell, when I click on the cell, the formula `A1 * 3 + 1` shows up.
And then the purpose of the `Range("A1").NumberFormat = "General"` is so that I can do this all over again by putting some other number in the cell.

Does anyone know how to do that?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood correctly but I think you want to insert a non-working formula to the cell you have selected, based on the value of that cell. If that is the case, below formula would work for you:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim myFormula As String

If IsNumeric(Selection.Value) = True And Selection.Value <> "" Then
    myFormula = Selection.Value & " * 3 + 1"
    Selection.Value = myFormula
End If

End Sub
```

Since the code is in `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event, it will work every time you select any cell. I have added an `If...Then` condition in order to not re-formulate an already-formulated cell or a blank cell.

Since the formula is working for the selected cell, you should exit the cell and re-enter in order to get it work for your numeric cell.

---

But still if you do not strictly need the formula created in the self cell but at another cell; a formula solution can also be used.

When your number is `A1`, write below formula to `B1` and copy down:

```
=ADDRESS(ROW(B1),COLUMN(B1)-1,1) & "* 3 + 1"
```